# Moving an Array to the next row in a Table

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following code to get variable `round2players` to be randomly assigned to the 2nd row in the table, here is my code so far:

```js
var x = 0, //starting column Index
    cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
    round1players = ['Forrest Gump', 'Tim Thomas', 'Pamila Henryson', 'Lotus Hobbes', 'Jerry Sparks', 'Kenneth Ingham'];
    round2players = ['Cyril Willard', 'Gale Frank', 'Aveline Derricks', 'Darcey Bullock', 'Jaiden Deering', 'Glenn Benn'];
    
function myFunction(round1playersArray)
{
 var round1names = round1playersArray.slice(0);
 while (round1names.length > 0 && x < cells.length) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*round1names.length);
    cells[x].innerHTML = round1names[randomIndex];
    x++;
    round1names.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 75%;
}
td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <body>
<table align=center>
<tr>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B & B</th>
<th>Ex-Tm #1</th>
<th>Ex-Tm #2</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div style="padding:25px" align=center>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(round1players)">Simulate to next round</button>
</div>
     </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: _"I am trying to get the following code to get variable `round2players` to be randomly assigned to the 2nd row in the table"_ `myFunction` is not called with `round2playersArray` as parameter at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: You need to pass in the second array into the function. Instead of getting all the td, I would get the tr. With the tr you can determine even or odd and loop through it while either using round1players or round2players to populate the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your arrays in another array. Now you have an array of arrays or multidimensional array. Multidimensional arrays are great for tables. Renamed the arrays because I hate typing long names. Details are commented in Snippet.

**Snippet**

```js
var round1 = ['Forrest Gump', 'Tim Thomas', 'Pamila Henryson', 'Lotus Hobbes', 'Jerry Sparks', 'Kenneth Ingham'];
var round2 = ['Cyril Willard', 'Gale Frank', 'Aveline Derricks', 'Darcey Bullock', 'Jaiden Deering', 'Glenn Benn'];
/* game is a multidimensional array. 
|  Each element is an array(sub-array).
|  Each sub-array is a row in a table.
|  Each element of a sub-array is a cell.
*/
var game = [round1, round2];
// count will be incremented per click of button
var count = 0;

function rounds(n, obj) {

  // Determine which sub-array to use
  var array = obj[n - 1];

  // Determine the specific <tr>
  var row = 'tr:nth-of-type(' + n + ')';

  // Reference each <td> cell of the <tr> row
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll('tbody ' + row + ' td');

  // Cell count
  var x = 0;

  // Separate each element of sub-array
  array = array.slice(0);

  // while loop establishes limits and iteration
  while (array.length > 0 && x < cells.length) {

    // Get a randomly generated number 
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

    /* On each iteration...
    |  ...insert the element of sub-array...
    |  ...that was determined by a randomly...
    |  ...generated index number.
    */
    cells[x].innerHTML = array[randomIndex];

    // Increment cell count
    x++;

    // Join each cell together in it's new order
    array.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <table align=center>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Black</th>
        <th>Blue</th>
        <th>B &amp; B</th>
        <th>Ex-Tm #1</th>
        <th>Ex-Tm #2</th>
        <th>Gryphons</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div style="padding:25px" align=center>
    <!-- This button's attribute event has a incremental counter, so each successive click will change the count parameter -->
    <button type="button" onclick="count++;rounds(count, game)">Simulate to next round</button>
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```